# dplyr: passing a data frame metric name through a function

Tags: r, dplyr

Some data

```
rws <- 810
Sessions <- ceiling(rnorm(rws, mean = 3000, sd = 300))
Registrations <- ceiling(rnorm(rws, mean = 800, sd = 100))
anotherMetric <- ceiling(rnorm(rws, mean = 800, sd = 100))
Date_Range = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-01-30"), by = 1)
myDF <- data.frame(Sessions, Registrations, Date_Range, anotherMetric)
```

If I wanted function that just groups by date and returns sum of metric totals for that date I think I want this:

```
metricByDate <- function(metric) {
  myDF %>%
    group_by(Date_Range) %>%
    summarise(metric = sum(metric))
}
```

However when I run `metricByDate(Sessions)` I get:

```
> metricByDate(Sessions)
# A tibble: 30 × 2
   Date_Range  metric
       <date>   <dbl>
1  2017-01-01 2424188
2  2017-01-02 2424188
3  2017-01-03 2424188
4  2017-01-04 2424188
5  2017-01-05 2424188...
```

Two things are wrong here: the metric name is "metric" and not "Sessions" like I hoped. And the sum of metrics appears to be the same for each date. In fact it looks like the sum total of myDF$Sessions for the whole df.

How can I get my function to take a parameter for metric name and then group and sum by that metric?

Comment: What is `rws`? Your data example is not yet reproducible.

Comment: So set `rws <- 30`.  Then print your `data.frame`.  Each dates appears once.  How do you want to 'group' that?

Comment: Woops, sorry overlooked rws. It's just a number, added rows <- 810 above. My goal is that for each date I get the sum of all Sessions

Comment: You need to use the [Standard Evaluation (SE)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) version of `dplyr` functions to be used within functions. So `summarise()` becomes `summarise_()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `data.table` more that `dplyr` so here is what I would do

#### Load data.table, convert `myDF`

```
R> library(data.table)
R> setDT(myDF)
```

#### Use data.table

The trick is to `parse()` a text variable first which then gets passed to `eval()`:

```
R> txt <- parse(text="Registrations")
R> myDF[ , sum(eval(txt)), by=Date_Range][1:5]
   Date_Range    V1
1: 2017-01-01 21260
2: 2017-01-02 22104
3: 2017-01-03 21690
4: 2017-01-04 22052
5: 2017-01-05 22384
```

Not that I show only the first five rows on purpose.

Same thing, now for the Sessions column:

```
R> txt <- parse(text="Sessions") 
R> myDF[ , sum(eval(txt)), by=Date_Range][1:5]
   Date_Range    V1
1: 2017-01-01 83117
2: 2017-01-02 80279
3: 2017-01-03 84694
4: 2017-01-04 78528
5: 2017-01-05 80248
R>
```

Better still, you can also sum over all columns at once:

```
R> myDF[ , lapply(.SD,sum), by=Date_Range][1:5]
   Date_Range Sessions Registrations
1: 2017-01-01    83117         21260
2: 2017-01-02    80279         22104
3: 2017-01-03    84694         21690
4: 2017-01-04    78528         22052
5: 2017-01-05    80248         22384
R>
```

Also, I used `set.seed(123)` at the very beginning to make this reproducible.